# Unsure how to find the dimension of $S = \operatorname{Span}\lbrace\sin\theta, \cos\theta, \sin\theta\cos\theta\rbrace$

Tags: linear-algebra

For $V = F(\mathbb R)$ be the space of real valued functions on the real line. $S$ is:  $$\ S = \operatorname{Span}\lbrace\sin\theta, \cos\theta, \sin\theta\cos\theta\rbrace. $$

I have to find the $\dim S $

I think that $\sin{\theta}$, $\cos{\theta}$, and $\sin\theta\cos\theta$ are linearly independent and if so then the dimension of $S$ is 3. However I am unsure how to prove this. I do know that I have to prove that $a = b = c = 0$ in the following equation:
$$a  \sin\theta + b\cos\theta + c \sin\theta\cos\theta = 0 $$
but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Please don't abuse the display equations, and avoid using them in the title.

Comment: Thanks @ArturoMagidin. I didn't know how to do the other type of equations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint.** Remember that
$$a\sin\theta + b\cos\theta + c(\sin\theta)(\cos\theta)=0,$$ 
is an equality of *functions*. That is, the function on the left is supposed to be *identically* zero. That is, you get $0$ for each and every value of $\theta$.
So then you get zero when $\theta=0$; what does that tell  you? And you also get $0$ when $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$; what does that tell you? And you also get $0$ when $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$. What does *that* tell  you?

Comment: Thank you for the help. That helped me solve it. :)